# Vibration non stop using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, vibration

I want to write a function when tapped I want to make phone vibrate non stop .

```
onPressed: () 
{
  Vibration.vibrate(duration: 100000,  );
},
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _cancel = false;
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Vibration Demo"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Timer.periodic(
                    const Duration(seconds: 1),
                    (Timer timer) {
                      if (_cancel) {
                        timer.cancel();
                        _cancel = false;
                        return false;
                      }
                      return Vibration.vibrate(duration: 1000);
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Start Vibrations"),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _cancel = true;
                },
                child: const Text("Stop Vibrations"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The argument type 'Timer' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: i cant use this

Comment: The argument type 'Timer' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Comment: it does not work at all.Now its does nothing

Comment: How are you using it, can you update your code?

Comment: Now i managed to work !Now it vibrates for long

Comment: it keeps on vibrating..If i tap ...cancle still its vibrating

Comment: You also have to cancel the timer.cancel(). I have updated the code and it now demonstrates how to Start and Stop the vibrations. Please like and accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.